# Backbone Marionette - trying to update one model in a collection deletes the other models

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a Collection:

```
var initializeUpfrontCost = function () {
    Entities.upfrontCost = new Entities.UpfrontCostCollection([
        { id: 'upfrontcost', name: 'upfrontcost', value: 0},
        { id: 'upfrontcostquote', name: 'upfrontcostquote', value: 0}


    ]);
};
```

I want to update just one row (model). I have:

```
   Entities.upfrontCost.set({id: 'upfrontcostquote', value:  "somevalue"});
```

But this seems to delete the other row. (A remove event is fired).

How can I update just this one row in my Collection?

Thanks

--Justin Wyllie

Answer (score 1):

You need `add({row}, {index: n})` to insert a row in the collection (or `add({row})` if you don't care about the position of the new row), but you must know which row to remove, so you can call `remove({oldrow})`.

You can find out the index for the `add` call with `_.indexOf(collection, {row})`;

If the add&row is not good enough, then you have to update the object in the collection and not replace it.

Links:

http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get) on `collection.get(id)`

You should be able to do something like:

```
var entity = Entities.upfrontCost.get('upfrontcostquote');

//Returns a model which you can then modify
entity.set({
   value: "some value"
});
```

When you call `collection.set()` in your original code it sets the value of the collection to the new input you gave it. Instead what you want to do is pull the individual `Model` out of the collection and modify that instead.